# Headings bunched together with \textsc

Tags: titles

I recently downloaded the [Title page with logo](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/title-page-with-logo/hrskypjpkrpd#.VmenLXarQ1L) LaTeX template. When I build the PDF the below `\textsc` headers appear bunched up. Is there a line spacing parameter I could pass as an argument to `\textsc`? Also how do I post the output of the below code? Is that possible I believe I have seen it in other posts? I did try searching for an answer to my question! Please let me know If I need be more clearer and demonstrate my output.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE Harvard University Extension School}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large CSCI E-59 Database Design \& Implementation}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Database Design \& Implementation Final Project}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries The ACME Wholesaler Sales Order Database}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
```

Comment: In "an arguement [_sic_] to `\textsx`," do you mean `\textsc`? If not, would you be able to include some code that uses `\textsx` so we can see how it is affecting your document?

Comment: To answer your question about adding the output, get it in image form (e.g. taking a screenshot and cropping if necessary, or directly converting if you can convert PDFs to PNGs easily). Then, when editing your post, look at the formatting bar on the top, and click on the 'insert image' button (which has a photo clipart on it, and is to the right of the braces `{}`).

Comment: all the size commands such as `{\LARGE Harvard University Extension School}` should be _outside_ the group as they are, if the text is longer than a line the linespacing will be incorrect (set for normalsize) the spacing is incorrect even for one line text but in that case the code works around the error by adding extra space at the forced linebreak `\\[1.5cm]`

Comment: You don't have any idea about LaTeX and searched for an example, which is completely ok. Uploading a template without having any idea is another thing. Creating a wikibook page without having any idea, not good.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do we have some question we can use as dupe, or do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B size commands should have par in their scope must be a dup, I'll look later see if I can find, if no one else has.